# CSS how to align elements

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a  shopping cart icon and Cart link, that I want to align with the other links on my menu (Register and Log in), but I am not very good with CSS.  Does anybody know how to do this?

See my picture...

[image]

Code:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">   </i>&nbsp;@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}      </span></li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id =       "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id =       "loginLink" })</li>      

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give your `li` items a `line-height` equals to the height of your navbar.

```
ul.nav > li {
   line-height: <your nav height>
```

I made an example for you here : [See CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHpaD)

Answer (score 0):

in your css file, use the attribute,

```
padding-top:0px;
```

for the links Register, Login.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `list-style-type:none;` to your `<ul>`

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eTymf/14/)

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```